# Difference between 3.6.11 and 3.6.11+?

Tags: cross-compilation

On my Raspberry Pi `uname -r` gives me `3.6.11+` but in the 3.6.y sources the make file has:

```
VERSION = 3
PATCHLEVEL = 6
SUBLEVEL = 11
EXTRAVERSION =
```

I am trying to compile a module. I (skipping some small steps):

- made a fresh SD card with `2013-09-25-wheezy-raspbian.img`
- downloaded `linux-rpi-3.6.y.tar.gz` from github
- downloaded `tools-master.tar.gz` from github
- copied `config.gz` from Rpi to Ubuntu
- compiled the kernel without changing `.config`
- compiled my module with the compiled kernel above

But when I tried to `insmod` I got "disagrees about version of symbol module_layout". At this point I am assuming it is because the source I got is 3.6.11 but my Rpi is running 3.6.11+.

How do I get the sources for 3.6.11+? Is there a Raspbian image that has just 3.6.11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between Linux 3.6.11 and 3.6.11+ is that `3.6.11+` has additional commits on top of 3.6.11 (the tag).

If you want to compile the **full** kernel image and modules, see http://elinux.org/RPi_Kernel_Compilation. However, it seems that you want to compile a single kernel module instead (a driver for your wireless USB stick?). In that case, you can save a lot of time, bytes and CPU time by compiling only the module you need.

### Requirements

- Kernel headers and `Makefile`s. On Arch Linux, this is the `linux-headers-raspberrypi` package, for Raspbian it's probably one of the `linux-headers-(version)` packages.
- If you are not using headers produced during the kernel build, but the source code (e.g. from git/tarball), then you will also need the kernel configuration file `.config`. This is required to produce modules that match the features enabled in the kernel.
- The kernel symbols file `Module.symvers`. Without this file, you will certainly get symbol mismatch errors.
- Kernel module source and Makefile for a module (the Makefile usually contains something like `obj-$(CONFIG_MODNAME) = modname.o` or `obj-m = modname.o`.)

### Compiling

There are basically two ways to build the kernel module:

- Compiling on the Pi. This is slow, but if you have just a single source file, then installation of the dependencies will probably be easier.
- Cross-compilation, this method makes you build the module on a faster device than your Pi (your Ubuntu installation on the laptop/desktop). It requires a suitable toolchain.

#### Compiling on Pi

When compiling directly on the Raspberry Pi, you would run something like this:

```
cd path/to/your/module/sources
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules -j2
```

If everything went well, you should now have a `.ko` file (e.g. `8192cu.ko`).

#### Cross-compilation

If you want to cross-compile the module, you will need a suitable toolchain. By suitable, I mean that you have to use exactly the same toolchain as was used for building the kernel. A discrepancy between the toolchain used for the kernel and module may lead to the most non-obvious errors at runtime. Getting this toolchain is out of the scope of this answer. See http://elinux.org/RPi_Kernel_Compilation#2._Cross_compiling_from_Linux for some more details. I built one a few months ago, see https://lekensteyn.nl/files/rpi/toolchains/ for instructions and a tarball.

(In the following section, replace `-j8` by `-j(number of cores times two)`.)

First, you need to set-up your build environment (adjust the prefix to something suitable for your toolchain):

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=/absolute/path/to/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-
# Alternatively:
export PATH=/absolute/path/to/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin:$PATH
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-
```

Prepare kernel sources:

```
# (tar xf linux-3.6.11.tar.gz or git clone whatever)
cd linux-3.6.11 # or something
gunzip < path/to/config.gz > .config
make -j8 prepare scripts
```

Proceed with the actual module compilation process:

```
cd path/to/your/module/sources
# Copy Module.symvers to current directory:
cp path/to/Module.symvers .
make -C path/to/kernel/sources M=$PWD modules -j8 ARCH=arm
```

If all went well, you should now have a `module.ko` file.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution to rebuild the kernel from source
([RPi Kernel Copliation](http://elinux.org/RPi_Kernel_Compilation))
and extract relevant header files
([Extract kernel headers](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/10299/10085))?