# How to tell if I am running the latest version of the Raspbian kernel?

Tags: raspbian, linux, kernel

I just finished building the Raspbian kernel according to the instructions in [Raspberry Pi Kernel Compilation Guide](http://elinux.org/RPi_Kernel_Compilation). Prior to this I was running the latest build from raspberrypi.org, 3.6.11+ #358. I am pretty sure that the [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) repository I pulled from [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) was the latest one, because the gitlogs show the latest commit [10bc58289](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/commit/10bc58289a7ebf6b1ab724636e0a16116278e339), but when I run `uname -a` I get "...3.6.11+ **#1**...".

My question is twofold:

1. How can I tell for sure whether I am running #1 or #358?
2. If I am running the older version of 3.6.11+, how do I build the latest version using the code from the repository? Is there a setting in the default `.config` file that I skipped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you have #1 is that you compiled your own kernel. If you want to always run the kernel from the Git repository, just use `rpi-update`.