# insmod segmentation fault error each time I insert a basic module

Tags: kernel, modules

I'm trying to build some kernel modules on RPI, the `ismond` work fine for some times, now the `insmod` command crash each time I try to insert a simple module. the kernel module compile without any error or warnings, and I'm not using any pointers. I used `modprobe` instedd of `insmod` and still getting same error

I got always this message, not matter what the kernel module contain

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/test_gpio_driver# insmod gpio.ko 
Segmentation fault
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/test_gpio_driver# 
Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jan  5 17:22:03 ...
 kernel:[  312.961379] Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] PREEMPT ARM

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jan  5 17:22:03 ...
 kernel:[  313.071855] Process insmod (pid: 2306, stack limit = 0xdb1d81b0)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jan  5 17:22:03 ...
 kernel:[  313.079360] Stack: (0xdb1d9e90 to 0xdb1da000)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jan  5 17:22:03 ...
 kernel:[  313.085167] 9e80:                                     bf0c413c c006d420 bf0c413c 00007fff

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jan  5 17:22:03 ...
 kernel:[  313.096194] 9ea0: c006a6e4 dc803000 00000000 c006a7b0 00000000 bf0c4278 bf0c413c db1d8018

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Jan  5 17:22:03 ...
 kernel:[  313.107386] 9ec0: ddef4b40 bf0c4130 db1d9f60 db1d9f8c ffffffff db1d9f14 00000000 00000000
```

my kernel module

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
static int __init mymodule_init(void)
{
 printk ("My module worked!\n");
        return 0;
}
static void __exit mymodule_exit(void)
{
 printk ("Unloading my module.\n");
        return;
}
module_init(mymodule_init);
module_exit(mymodule_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the request_irq and free_irq calls?

Comment: no, even if i keep just the init and exit function with empty body, I got same error

Answer (score 1):

I also had a problem similar to yours and the solution was to use rpi-update to update the kernel and rpi-source.

So, steps:

1. `sudo rpi-update` and when it's done, reboot the Raspi
2. Install the rpi-source: `sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/notro/rpi-source/master/rpi-source -O /usr/bin/rpi-source && sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/rpi-source && /usr/bin/rpi-source -q --tag-update`
3. You may need GCC 4.8 so:`sudo apt-get install -y gcc-4.8 g++-4.8` and 
   `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 20
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 50
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.6 20
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 50`
   You whould replace in the previous command the gcc-4.6 with your version of gcc
4. Install ncurses-devel: `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev`; It's needed by rpi-source.
5. Run `rpi-source`

This steps worked for me and I could compile and install a driver.

Comment: i followed those steps and still get same `segmentation fault`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no mismatch between the kernel you compiled for and the kernel you run? For example, you installed different Linux headers on you Raspberry with different version than your kernel. 
Possible solution [HERE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10289/raspbian-kernel-module-segmentation-fault)

Comment: I updated my kernel with rpi-update to `3.12.36+` and installed the source as indicated in http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15902/dht11-module-compilation-error, but the kernel didn't created `/lib/modules/3.12.36+/build` directory, so the available sources are obsolete (perhaps for 3.12.35+).  with 3.12.35+I compile but get the `segmentation fault` error